# Javascript exit full screen swf

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, swfobject

Trying to exit fullscreen of a swf using javascript.

Managed to do so by hiding the showing the player.  With jQuery, like this...
$('.player').hide();
$('.player').show();

Was wondering if there was a better way to do this?

Thanks

Edit: also I'm using swfobject if that helps in anyway.

Comment: Why can't you use the "Esc" key?

Comment: Using javascript??? How?